# I can't login as a chatbot into my Facebook account using Python and fbchat

Tags: python, facebook, chatbot, messenger

This is my code:

```
from fbchat import Client, log
from fbchat.models import *

Email = '****'
Password = '****'

class Jervis(Client):

    def onMessage(
            self,
            mid=None,
            author_id=None,
            message=None,
            message_object=None,
            thread_id=None,
            thread_type=ThreadType.USER,
            ts=None,
            metadata=None,
            msg=None,
            **kwargs
    ):
        self.markAsRead(author_id)
        log.into("Message {} from {} in {}".format(message_object, thread_id, thread_type))
        msgText = message_object.text

        reply = "hello, i'm leonel"

        if author_id != self.uid:
            self.send(Message(text=reply), thread_id, thread_type=thread_type)

        self.markAsRead(author_id, thread_id)



client = Jervis(email= Email, password= Password)
client.listen()
```

This is an error I am getting:

```
Attempt #1 failed, retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nmzub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_client.py", line 205, in login
    self._state = State.login(
  File "C:\Users\nmzub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_state.py", line 153, in login
    raise _exception.FBchatUserError(
fbchat._exception.FBchatUserError: Login failed. Check email/password. (Failed on url: https://m.facebook.com/login/?email=nmzubayeralam%40gmail.com&cuid=AYi9BVk7M1mLfuwkBYpPmyt9BVGFy1ap622CkGSZBOYf4BHSSM37rIhOWewqwnHj71hLpWdmq_gxCwBMrcCny-5RdF34vZFGDJecmjC4HaXfYXNuUlNhAuilo-ZKkvrVGCCR5rsOn5zfna0lzZx2kXGwtz13F_Pkn3FEmW214vFT0JiE-4t-E8WlAWAA3LLfFjjMnE6SmGWDvMm5PhrQAeddGMCnmAqZmNaQVUEbxesTz2fR2Nfv21-_kQMJmyqPHBYjOAniWnOvpjsDzGPVoleEqWPUeWM6mVTRW3taVSpsRg&li=ZYx9YQ1i7Ee6FaHjRwq6wiXb&e=1348060&shbl=1&refsrc=deprecated&_rdr)
Attempt #2 failed, retrying
```

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't let you programmetically interact with their website except using their API. And there is no API for Messenger chats.

Comment: I saw a guy who used a method of Jervis chatbot. please check this link it will make sense what I'm trying to do.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIcZZCnFcH4 @WizKid

Comment: Sure people use it. Just be aware your account might be banned because Facebook doesn't allow it

Comment: @WizKid Thanks to aware of me but I still want to try this method of educational purpose. can help me to figure out what is the problem? it will be great help :)

Comment: I would suggest talking to the people that wrote fbchat. Or you need to debug their code.

Comment: @WizKid okay friend.

Comment: @ZubayerAlam Your account credentials were redacted from the edit history by a moderator. However, you should still consider changing your password just to be safe.